# one function for multiple buttons with different id

Tags: jquery, button

I have

```
$('#BtOpenFile').click(function () { SetTimeextendBtn(); });
```

But There are multiple buttons with different IDs like `#BtAquire, #BtDelete, ...` and I want to use `SetTimeextendBtn()` for all of my buttons. I don't want to repeat the function.

How can we do that?

Comment: So what did you end up using? Multiple IDs in a selector or a class?

Comment: Multiple IDs in a selector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add multiple ids in selector using comma

```
$('#BtOpenFile, #BtAquire').click(function () { SetTimeextendBtn(this); });
```

Pass the current object to SetTimeextendBtn(this);

```
function SetTimeextendBtn(source)
{
    alert(source.id);
}
```

One other approach should be considered by using the same class to which you want to bind the click handler. Suppose you have button with common class .btn

```
 $('.btn').click(function () { SetTimeextendBtn(this); });
```

**Note:** if your click handler is just calling a function and passing the current object, then you can directly pass the function to click:

```
$('.btn').click(SetTimeextendBtn);
```

You can access the source button (object) in `SetTimeextendBtn` using `this` for DOM object and `$(this)` for jQuery object for button being clicked.

Comment: If the anonymous function does nothing else then it is not  elegant to call that one thing in a function

Answer (score 6):

Use a class.

Also if there is nothing else going on in the anonymous function, scrap it and attach the other function directly

`$('.BtActions').on("click",SetTimeextendBtn);`

If you need to know what was clicked, you can access the button directly in the function:

```
function SetTimeextendBtn() {
  var id = this.id; // or $(this).prop("id");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Attribute Starts With Selector **[[name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** , this will select all elements which have id's starting with `Bt`. But it's better to use common `class` name for all those button.

```js
$('[id^=Bt]').click(function() {
  SetTimeextendBtn(this);
});

function SetTimeextendBtn(ele) {
  alert(ele.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Bt1">a</button>
<button id="Bt2">b</button>
<button id="Bt3">c</button>
<button id="Bt4">d</button>
<button id="Bt5">e</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('#BtOpenFile, #BtAquire, #BtDelete').click(function () {
    SetTimeextendBtn();
});
```

Alternatively you can add a class to the buttons and use a [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$('.extend-time').click(function () {
    SetTimeextendBtn();
});
```

As others have mentioned already, you don't need the anonymous function wrapper if you're just calling a function:

```
$('.extend-time').click(SetTimeextendBtn);
```